# What if I forget to pay rent?

Tags: monopoly

Is the rule of not paying rent if you aren't asked for it, in the rules of **Monopoly**? Or is this something that people have made up? When is this ok?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [official rules](http://richard_wilding.tripod.com/monorules.htm#payingrent), property owners must ask for the rent before the **player after the** next player rolls the dice or they forfeit the rent.

> The owner may not collect the rent if they fail to ask for it before the second player following throws the dice.

So if the players are labelled A to D, and A should pay rent:

```
A ... B .x. C ... D
```

The lessor should request rent before C throws the dice, at the position marked X.

Comment: But what happens if you forget?

Comment: If *who* forgets? The debtor has no reason to try and remember. The creditor has to remember (and ask), or forfeits rent.

Comment: @Pureferret: I think the sentence you somehow missed in the rules was "The owner may not collect the rent if they fail to ask for it before the second player following throws the dice."

Comment: @Jefromi that is the answer I'm after! I might edit my question later to reflect that.

Comment: Second player following is a MUCH better rule than "before the next player rolls the dice".  Stops the horrible yet inevitable scenario of players trying to snatch the dice up and quickly roll them just as the creditor is opening his mouth.

Comment: @thesunneversets: That *is* the rule... when I originally answered this from my iPhone, I missed that detail. Guess everyone else did, too!

Comment: Let's not forget that the basic reason for playing board games is a social event.  I always anouce gentlemen rules at the begining of a game wich means the debtor always pays even if the creditor doesn't notice it.  We must go to the washroom from time to time, get a drink, put our kids to bed or roll a joint.  If the debtor must always ask, it slows the game down, makes it unfair & antisocial.

Comment: If you're drinking, smoking weed, and concerned about "slow[ing] the game down", I would strongly suggest you find a more modern game. [Cockroach Poker](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/11971/cockroach-poker), [Secret Hitler](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/188834/secret-hitler), and [WCRR](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/179245/world-championship-russian-roulette) all feature much more interactive, sneaky, and hilarious play.

Comment: (that previous comment being directed at @MartinCharette)

Comment: There is something up with that mobile site. I couldn't copy and paste from it at all without it jumping around and trying to show pop-ups. I suggest we find an alternative.

Answer (score -4):

By the official rules you must pay rent due

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for your input! I'd suggest you add a link to the rules you're citing and provide a supporting quote, because otherwise your answer is unlikely to be taken seriously given that it contradicts an answer that *does* cite a source (and is highly upvoted and accepted).